# easydropdown depending select

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox, easydropdown

I am using easydropdown (https://github.com/patrickkunka/easydropdown) to style my select dropdown fields.

So far, so good.

Yet, when trying to make 2 select boxes dependable, the 2nd box remains with the initial values.
I tried jsfiddle, jet was unable to add the resources correctly it seems:
example:

http://jsfiddle.net/49FK9/46/

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.easydropdown/2.1.4/jquery.easydropdown.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.easydropdown/2.1.4/themes/easydropdown.css">
<select name="test1" class="dropdown" id="test1">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="test2" class="dropdown" id="test2">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>

    <script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById('test2').selectedIndex = document.getElementById('test1').selectedIndex;
}, false);</script>
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.easydropdown/2.1.4/jquery.easydropdown.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.easydropdown/2.1.4/themes/easydropdown.css">
<select name="test1" class="dropdown" id="test1">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
    <select name="test2" class="dropdown" id="test2">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('test1').addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById('test2').selectedIndex = document.getElementById('test1').selectedIndex;
}, false);
</script>
```

Comment: i forgot to add the script tags in the question, sorry for the confusion - i updated the question & added a jfiddle. yet, it doesnt work this way

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it to work, but used bootstrap-select instead of easydropdown.

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); did the job